# How to accept a database and print out a list in python

Tags: python, database, list, function, dictionary

So I have to create a simple program that accepts a database with a bunch of artists and their works of art with the details of the art. There is a given artist and I have to search through the database to find all the ones where they have to same artist and return them. I'm not allowed to use other built in functions nor import anything. Can someone tell me why its creating the error and what it means?

```
def works_by_artists(db,artists): 
  newlist = {}
  for a in db.keys():
    for b in db[artists]:
      if a == b:
        newlist.append(a);
  return newlist
```

This prints out an error:

```
for b in db[artists]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: there's a lot of undefined variables here: b and x should be a list...

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can accept only some kinds of values as keys. In particular, they must be *hashable*, which mean they cannot change while in the dictionary ("immutable"), and there must be a function known to Python that takes the value and returns a nonnegative integer that somehow represents the integer. Integers, floats, strings, and tuples are immutable and hashable, while standard lists, dictionaries, and sets are not. The hash value of the key is used to store the key-value pair in the standard Python dictionary. This method was chosen for the sake of speed of looking up a key, but the speed comes at the cost of limiting the possible key values. Other ways could have been chosen, but this works well for the dictionary's intended purpose in Python.

You tried to execute the line `for b in db[artists]:` while the current value of `artists` was not hashable. This is an error. I cannot say what the value of `artists` was, since the value was a parameter to the function and you did not show the calling code.

So check which value of `artists` was given to function `works_by_artists()` that caused the displayed error. Whatever created that value is the actual error in your code.